# Tshark - Two types of OpenFlow FLOW_MOD packets

Tags: tcpdump, sdn, mininet, tshark, openflow

I am running an SDN controller on port #6633 and then capturing the packets going to it using *tshark* which is give me following output:

`*18 0.029550379    127.0.0.1 ?~F~R 127.0.0.1    OpenFlow 138 Type: OFPT_FLOW_MOD*
 19 0.031562043    127.0.0.1 ?~F~R 127.0.0.1    TCP 88 8984?~F~R56292 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=86 Win=86 Len=22 TSval=7474079 TSecr=7474075
 20 0.031591119    127.0.0.1 ?~F~R 127.0.0.1    TCP 66 56292?~F~R8984 [ACK] Seq=86 Ack=23 Win=86 Len=0 TSval=7474079 TSecr=7474079
 21 0.031786109    127.0.0.1 ?~F~R 127.0.0.1    TCP 163 56292?~F~R8984 [PSH, ACK] Seq=86 Ack=23 Win=86 Len=97 TSval=7474079 TSecr=7474079
 *22 0.031958834    127.0.0.1 ?~F~R 127.0.0.1    OpenFlow 146 Type: OFPT_FLOW_MOD*
 23 0.032035439    127.0.0.1 ?~F~R 127.0.0.1    TCP 66 47418?~F~R6633 [ACK] Seq=341 Ack=169 Win=44032 Len=0 TSval=7474079 TSecr=7474079
 24 0.032732179    127.0.0.1 ?~F~R 127.0.0.1    TCP 88 8984?~F~R56292 [PSH, ACK] Seq=23 Ack=183 Win=86 Len=22 TSval=7474080 TSecr=7474079
 25 0.038687398 36:68:ff:8e:d1:9c ?~F~R Broadcast    OpenFlow 126 Type: OFPT_PACKET_IN`

As per my application, there should be only one flow rule installed in switch. When I used the **dpctl dump-flows** in mininet then it also returned me only one flow rule. Now I have doubt because there are two flow mod packets.

In Packet #18 and 22 both are OFPT_FLOW_MOD packets, but if you see then both packets have a different number after **OpenFlow** keyword, see the third column. Could anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

There's a number after ***every*** protocol, not just OpenFlow packets.  Take a look at the others, for example packet #19 "TCP 88".

In all likelihood, you have a Wireshark `Length` column following the `Protocol` column, and this value is just the number of bytes in the packet.  Check your Wireshark columns; tshark just uses the same ones by default.